# XeLaTeX error: File ended while scanning use of \__tl_rescan:w. \begin{document}

Tags: xetex

Does anyone know what this error means? I have been googling this for a few hours now, but I don't understand. It started when I updated my MikTeX files. After some googling I think it has something to with package l3kernel and unicode-math not being able to play nice with each other.

I'm especially curious where this error originates from. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without a minimal example of code that shows the issue it's impossible to say anything.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/266: probably you have some input that was relying on certain artefacts of the older implementation inside `expl3`. However, without an example it's hard to help! (There will be an `expl3` update to CTAN in a day or so to address this.)

Comment: See also https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/321: Will's already got a fix sorted

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. How do I implement this fix on my computer?

Comment: If you’re using a version packaged with your distro, wait for an update.  If you installed TeX Live manually, run `tlmgr update --self --all` as the proper user regularly.  (I have a shell script that does this as the right user.)

Comment: @Lorehead: As the update isn't on CTAN yet you don't get it with tlmgr, and as Jochem has miktex he hasn't tlmgr anyway.

Comment: @JosephWright: Is there some way to temporarly patch a document? miktex has no means to revert a package installation and I don't know how long it will take until the update is there.

Comment: So he does.  I should have read more carefully.  If he needs it before MikTeX updates, it’s up on GitHub at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math

Answer (score 2):

Ulrike asked for a patch in the comments above. This is untested, but might work:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{ucharcat}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \exp_last_unbraced:NNx { \::N \::x_unbraced \::: }
\cs_set:Npn \@@_cs_set_eq_active_char:Nw #1 = "#2 \q_nil
  {
    \exp_last_unbraced:NNx \cs_gset_eq:NN #1 { \Ucharcat "#2 ~ 12 ~ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, the file https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/archive/v0.8b.zip contains the fix.  You should be able to install it over the files in your MikTeX directory (backing up the old ones first, of course), or just copy them to the directory where you’re currently running XeLaTeX.

To do this:

- Unzip the archive.
- Run `tex unicode-math.dtx`.
- Move the `.sty` files to your local texmf tree or simply the folder where you need the temporary fix.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me now. I don't know anything about MikTeX but surely those steps won't overwrite the installed copy? So they won't 'do this' if 'this' refers to overwriting the original `unicode-math.dtx`. (Which wouldn't probably help because I'm assuming it is using `unicode-math.sty` anyhow.) So while the instructions seem reasonable, they don't (fortunately) seem to do what it claims on the tin ;).

Comment: Edited Will Robertson’s edit to remove my original description, which clashed with his instructions.  In a few days, the update should be out everywhere.

Comment: @lorehead -- oops, I was too hasty. Thanks for the correction :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot people. This solved the problem! Now I can compile my thesis again and make my deadline, which is in 30 minutes!